# Print certain Rows of dataframe which do not fit in regex condition or certain condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Dataframe:

```
              Date Clearing Member PAN Trading Member PAN   CPCode       CPPAN  ... ValueofMTM1 TCM_CM_ID TCM_PRIMARY_MEMBER_CODE  TCM_TM_ID  CCD_CLI_CD
0    1/12/2021          AAACM6094R         AAACM6094R      123  GMAPS5536A  ...  1234567890.12345    M50219                     220        220        AC79
1    1/13/2021          AAACM6094R         AAACM6094R      123  GMAPS5536A  ...  1234567890    M50219                     220        220        AD03
2    1/14/2021          AAACM6094R         AAACM6094R      123  GMAPS5536A  ...  1234567890    M50220                     220        220        N552
3    1/15/2021          AAACM6094R         AAACM6094R      123  GMAPS5536A  ...  1234567890    M50219                     220        220        KF99
4    1/16/2021          AAACM6094R         AAACM6094R      123  GMAPS5536A  ...  1234567890    M50219                     220        220        D745
```

I need to Perform validation on each column one by one and print remove rows from dataframe and print those rows in new dataframe. similarily filtering out rows after each column validation.

for example :

```
NumberRegex = r"^[0-9]\d{1,20}(?:.\d{1,3})?$"
df=df['ValueofMTM1'].apply(str).str.contains(NumberRegex, regex=True)
```

This should remove my first row of dataframe and output dataframe should look like  and row which did not suit condition should be stored in other dataframe

```
              Date Clearing Member PAN Trading Member PAN   CPCode       CPPAN  ... ValueofMTM1 TCM_CM_ID TCM_PRIMARY_MEMBER_CODE  TCM_TM_ID  CCD_CLI_CD
1    1/13/2021          AAACM6094R         AAACM6094R      123  GMAPS5536A  ...  1234567890    M50219                     220        220        AD03
2    1/14/2021          AAACM6094R         AAACM6094R      123  GMAPS5536A  ...  1234567890    M50220                     220        220        N552
3    1/15/2021          AAACM6094R         AAACM6094R      123  GMAPS5536A  ...  1234567890    M50219                     220        220        KF99
4    1/16/2021          AAACM6094R         AAACM6094R      123  GMAPS5536A  ...  1234567890    M50219                     220        220        D745
```

Error Row :

```
          Date Clearing Member PAN Trading Member PAN   CPCode       CPPAN  ... ValueofMTM1 TCM_CM_ID TCM_PRIMARY_MEMBER_CODE  TCM_TM_ID  CCD_CLI_CD
0    1/12/2021          AAACM6094R         AAACM6094R      123  GMAPS5536A  ...  1234567890.12345    M50219                     220        220        AC79
```

Next example

```
df=df['TCM_CM_ID ']== 'M50219'
```

This will give output dataframe as 2nd rows does not matches condition :

```
              Date Clearing Member PAN Trading Member PAN   CPCode       CPPAN  ... ValueofMTM1 TCM_CM_ID TCM_PRIMARY_MEMBER_CODE  TCM_TM_ID  CCD_CLI_CD
1    1/13/2021          AAACM6094R         AAACM6094R      123  GMAPS5536A  ...  1234567890    M50219                     220        220        AD03
3    1/15/2021          AAACM6094R         AAACM6094R      123  GMAPS5536A  ...  1234567890    M50219                     220        220        KF99
4    1/16/2021          AAACM6094R         AAACM6094R      123  GMAPS5536A  ...  1234567890    M50219                     220        220        D745
```

Error row :

```
          Date Clearing Member PAN Trading Member PAN   CPCode       CPPAN  ... ValueofMTM1 TCM_CM_ID TCM_PRIMARY_MEMBER_CODE  TCM_TM_ID  CCD_CLI_CD
0    1/12/2021          AAACM6094R         AAACM6094R      123  GMAPS5536A  ...  1234567890.12345    M50219                     220        220        AC79
2    1/14/2021          AAACM6094R         AAACM6094R      123  GMAPS5536A  ...  1234567890    M50220                    220        220        N552
```

Similarily other column validations. How to Perform this activity:

My code:

```
    vaex_df2 = pd.read_csv('D:\\test\\CR6645DOC\\GMAPS5536C_01092021_01.csv')
    vaex_df3=pd.read_csv('D:\\test\\CR6645DOC\\CM_TM_UCC_2.csv')

    df = pd.merge(vaex_df2, vaex_df3,  how='inner', left_on=['Clearing Member PAN','Trading Member PAN','Client PAN'], right_on = ['OFF_TM_PANNO','OFF_TM_PANNO_1','CCD_PAN_NO']).drop_duplicates()
    df.drop(['OFF_TM_PANNO','OFF_TM_PANNO_1','CCD_PAN_NO'],axis=1, inplace=True)
    NumberRegex = r"^[0-9]\d{1,20}(?:.\d{1,3})?$"
    df=df['ValueofMTM'].apply(str).str.contains(NumberRegex, regex=True))
    df=df['AType'].isin(['P','C']))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your right-hand side expression returns a filter of `True` or `False` values:
`df['ValueofMTM'].astype(str).str.contains(NumberRegex, regex=True))`
Instead, you could use `.loc` in combination with the **negation** of each condition as follows:

```
df = df.loc[~df['ValueofMTM'].astype(str).str.contains(NumberRegex, regex=True)), :]
print(df)
```

A common pattern is:
`df.loc[<condition as a Series or lambda>, <columns>]`
This will restrict your DF to rows that satisfy your condition. Use the negation (`~`) operator on your condition to select the complement instead.